# How can we create our own google lab feature?

Tags: plugins, google-apps

is it possible and how ?
can any one share the URL that can help to create new google lab feature..

Answer (score 1):

Don;t think so, unless you join Google. See http://www.googlelabs.com/faq#whobuilds